# n-th order derivative of a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the n-th derivative of the following functions:

1. $y = x\sqrt{1+x^2}$
2. $y = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}$

All help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to solve these problems?

Comment: Of course I did. I computed some of the first value, then used WolframAlpha to compute the higher one and tried to guess the general formula, but I couldn't. Here is some of its value if it can help:
$$f' = \dfrac{x}{2\sqrt{(x-x^2)^3}$$
$$f'' = \dfrac{x(4x-1)}{4\sqrt{(x-x^2)^5}$$

Comment: I need the n-th derivative, not at a particular point. I don't know why our teacher gave us such complicated problems. I'm just a high-school student.

Comment: Try to calculate the derivative of first, second, third etc order and look for the patterns to find the general form of the derivative for any $n$.

Comment: Looks like you didn't read anything I wrote, @Lullaby. The work you tell me to do is exactly the one I said that I couldn't do and that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: At least, for the second case you can rewrite $y= x^{1/2}(1-x)^{-1/2}$ and then write the $n$-th derivative as a sum by using the Leibnitz rule. This doesn't really work for the first case, since you would need a generic formula for $n$-th derivative of $\sqrt{1+x^2}$, which is not that obvious (if it exists).

Comment: $$y(x) = x(x-i)^{\frac{1}{2}}(x+i)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: Thank you @TZakrevskiy. I solved the second problem thanks to your hint. :D

Answer (score 2):

Let be $\varphi_1(x)=\sqrt{x^2+x^4}=f_1(g_1(x))$ where $f_1(x)=\sqrt x$ and $g_1(x)=x^2+x^4$, and $\varphi_2(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-1}}=f_2(g_2(x))$ where $f_2(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ and $g_2(x)=\frac{1}{x}-1$

It's easy to see that
$$
f_1^{(n)}(x)=\frac{\sqrt\pi x^{\frac{1}{2}-n}}{2\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}-n\right)}\qquad\text{and}\qquad f_2^{(n)}(x)=\frac{\sqrt\pi x^{-\frac{1}{2}-n}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-n\right)}
$$
and
$$
g_1'(x)=2x+4x^3\quad g_1''(x)=2+12x^2\quad g_1'''(x)=24 x\quad g_1^{(4)}=24\quad g_1^{(n)}=0\;\text{for}\; n\ge 0
$$
and
$$
g_2^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^n \,n!\,x^{-1-n}
.
$$
Thus, we can use the  [Faà di Bruno's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaadiBrunosFormula.html) in the classical form
$$
\varphi^{(n)}(x)=\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(g(x))
=\sum \frac{n!}{m_1!\,m_2!\,\cdots\,m_n!}\cdot
f^{(m_1+\cdots+m_n)}(g(x))\cdot
\prod_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{g^{(j)}(x)}{j!}\right)^{m_j}
$$
where the sum is over all $n$-tuples of nonnegative integers $(m_1,\ldots,m_n)$ satisfying the constraint
$1\cdot m_1+2\cdot m_2+3\cdot m_3+\cdots+n\cdot m_n=n$ or  the Faà di Bruno's formula expressed in terms of [Bell polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellPolynomial.html) $B_{n,k}(x_1,\ldots,x_{n−k+1})$
$$\varphi^{(n)}(x)=\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(g(x))= \sum_{k=1}^n f^{(k)}(g(x))\cdot B_{n,k}\left(g'(x),g''(x),\dots,g^{(n-k+1)}(x)\right).$$

Answer (score 2):

For the first function, the best I can get is a recursive definition. I get

$$y^{(n)}=\frac{P_n}{\left(x^2+1 \right)^{n-1/2}}$$

where $P_n$ is the polynomial of degree at most $n+1$ defined by

$$P_0=x$$

$$P_n=\left(x^2+1\right)P_{n-1}'-(2n-3)xP_{n-1}$$

($P_{n-1}'$ is the derivative of $P_{n-1}$.)

This sequence of polynomials has several interesting properties:

a. The odd-numbered $P_n$ have only even powers of $x$, and vice-versa.

b. There is cancellation for $P_3$, so for $n \ge 3$ the degree of $P_n$ is at most $n-3$. I have not seen such cancellation for any higher degree.

Here are the first few $P_n$:

$$P_0=x$$
$$P_1=2x^2+1$$
$$P_2=2x^3+3x$$
$$P_3=3$$
$$P_4=-15x$$
$$P_5=90x^2-15$$
$$P_6=-630x^3+315x$$

Comment: I am curious. Why the downvote for this answer? I admit this is not a great answer, but it is valid and uses concepts I understood in high school. The OP asked for "all help," and this does seem to be of some help.

Comment: Yes, I find this answer quite interesting. I was unable to find $P(n)$, and this might help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To shorten the notation, define $t=\sqrt{1+x^2}$, so that $t'=x/\sqrt{1+x^2}=x/t$.

Then
$$(xt)'=t+xt'=\color{blue}{t+\frac{x^2}t},$$
$$(xt)''=t'+2\frac{x}t-\frac{x^2}{t^2}t'=\color{blue}{3\frac xt-\frac{x^3}{t^3}},$$
$$(xt)'''
=3\frac1t-3\frac x{t^2}t'-3\frac{x^2}{t^3}+3\frac{x^3}{t^4}t'
=\color{blue}{3\frac1t-6\frac{x^2}{t^3}+3\frac{x^4}{t^5}},$$
$$(xt)''''
=-3\frac1{t^2}t'-12\frac x{t^3}+18\frac{x^2}{t^4}t'+12\frac{x^3}{t^5}-15\frac{x^4}{t^6}t'
=\color{blue}{-15\frac x{t^3}+30\frac{x^3}{t^5}-15\frac{x^5}{t^7}},$$
$$(xt)'''''
=-15\frac 1{t^3}+45\frac x{t^4}t'
+90\frac{x^2}{t^5}-150\frac{x^3}{t^6}t'
-75\frac{x^4}{t^7}+105\frac{x^5}{t^8}t'\\
=\color{blue}{-15\frac 1{t^3}
+135\frac{x^2}{t^5}
-225\frac{x^4}{t^7}+105\frac{x^6}{t^9}}.$$
You see a pattern emerge, a sum of an increasing number of fractions $(2,2,3,3,4\dots)$ with a power of $x$ at the numerator and a power of $t$ at the denominator $(0,2;1,3;0,2,4;1,3,5;0,2,4,6\dots)$ and $(\bar1,1;1,3;1,3,5;3,5,7;3,5,7,9\dots)$. Then it is possible to generalize those sequences for larger $n$.

Now the coefficients are the hardest  to determine as the recurrences are complex.